# deallocating is not allowed when attempting to load the view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am using swift to send a message to my server, however, I am not able to get an alert popup to happen when it is over. Here is the code.

```
func sendSimpleCommand(siteId: Int, command: String) -> Int {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, commandUrl, parameters: ["site": siteId, "command": command, "device": "ios"])
        .responseJSON { response in
            //print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            switch response.result {
            case .Success(_):
                print("success code back from api server for command sent")
                let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Command Sent", message: "Your \(command) has been sent.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in
                }
                alertView.addAction(alertAction)
            case .Failure(_):
                print("FAIL code back from api server for command sent")
                let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Connect Error", message: "Network error, please try again", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in
                }
                alertView.addAction(alertAction)
            }
    }
    return 1
}




@IBAction func startButtonTouch(sender: UIButton) {
   let helper = HelperActions()
   let site = ActiveSite.sharedInstance.siteObject
   let command: String = "start"
   sendSimpleCommand(site.id , command: command)
}
```

Now when I run it, the network communication happens correctly but then I get an error and the alert window never shows up.

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior

Comment: Where are you trying to present it?

Comment: in a UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Just add this single line on top of your code to make an global request of UIAlertController.

As in swift we don't have to deallocate any views. Swift language handels it on their side.

```
let alertView : UIAlertController?
```

remove all declaration of alertView in the class

> Edit

```
func sendSimpleCommand(siteId: Int, command: String) -> Int {
Alamofire.request(.GET, commandUrl, parameters: ["site": siteId, "command": command, "device": "ios"])
    .responseJSON { response in
        //print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(_):
            print("success code back from api server for command sent")
            alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Command Sent", message: "Your \(command) has been sent.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in
            }
            alertView.addAction(alertAction)
        case .Failure(_):
            print("FAIL code back from api server for command sent")

            alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Connect Error", message: "Network error, please try again", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in
            }
            alertView.addAction(alertAction)
        }
}
return 1
}




@IBAction func startButtonTouch(sender: UIButton) {
   let helper = HelperActions()
   let site = ActiveSite.sharedInstance.siteObject
   let command: String = "start"
   sendSimpleCommand(site.id , command: command)
}
```

Comment: how do i do that If i have to instantiate it with attributes ?